# Wicket - How to use ListView in custom form component?

Tags: listview, wicket, wicket-1.6

I'm trying to implement a custom form component which contains a ListView.

**My Custom Form Component:**

```
public class NotificationDataListPanel extends FormComponentPanel {

    private ListView<NotificationDataBean> listView = null;

    public NotificationDataListPanel(String id) {
        this(id, null);
    }

    public NotificationDataListPanel(String id, List list) {
        super(id);

        listView = new ListView<NotificationDataBean>("listView") {
            @Override
            protected void populateItem(final ListItem<NotificationDataBean> item) {
                final NotificationDataPanel dataPanel = new NotificationDataPanel("dataPanel", new Model<NotificationDataBean>() {
                    @Override
                    public NotificationDataBean getObject() {
                        return item.getModel().getObject();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void setObject(final NotificationDataBean value) {
                        item.setModelObject(value);
                    }
                });
                item.add(dataPanel);
            }
        };
        add(listView);

        add(new AjaxLink("addNewNDPanel") {
            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                List<NotificationDataBean> modelObject = listView.getModelObject();
                if (modelObject == null) {
                    modelObject = new ArrayList<NotificationDataBean>();
                }
                modelObject.add(new NotificationDataBean());
                listView.setModelObject(modelObject);

                target.add(this);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeRender() {
        super.onBeforeRender();
        List<NotificationDataBean> modelObject = (List<NotificationDataBean>) getModelObject();
        if (modelObject != null && !modelObject.isEmpty()) {
            listView.setModelObject(modelObject);
        } else {
            listView.setModel(new Model());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void convertInput() {
        List<NotificationDataBean> modelObject = listView.getModelObject();

        setConvertedInput(modelObject);
        updateModel();
    }
}
```

`NotificationDataPanel` works great in forms on its own and on the other hand I could use it in `ListView` in forms (not in separated form component).

**Works fine:**

```
    final Form form = new Form("form", new CompoundPropertyModel(testFormBean));

    final ListView<NotificationDataBean> strs = new ListView<NotificationDataBean>("notiL") {
        @Override
        protected void populateItem(final ListItem<NotificationDataBean> item) {
            final NotificationDataPanel quxField = new NotificationDataPanel("str", new Model<NotificationDataBean>() {
                @Override
                public NotificationDataBean getObject() {
                    return item.getModel().getObject();
                }

                @Override
                public void setObject(final NotificationDataBean value) {
                    item.setModelObject(value);
                }
            });
            item.add(quxField);
        }
    };
    form.add(strs);
```

But when I tried to use it in `ListView` in separated form component I got this exception.

```
Last cause: No get method defined for class: class TestFormBean expression: listView
```

**NOT OK**

```
    final Form form = new Form("form", new CompoundPropertyModel(testFormBean));
    form.add(new NotificationDataListPanel("notiL"));
```

**And `TestFormBean` class:**

```
class TestFormBean implements Serializable {
    List<NotificationDataBean> notiL;
}
```

The word, **listView** in exception refers to `ListView` id in `NotificationDataListPanel`.

Thanks in advance for any tips how to fix this and please accept my apologies for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not giving a model to your ListView, so it will search for one up in the component hierarchy.
CompountPropertyModel serves models to child components, and it uses their id to find a property on their model.

You probably just want to do:

```
new ListView<NotificationDataBean>("listView", list);
```